# How to convert RNN into a regression net?

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

If the output is a *tanh* function, then I get a number between -1 and 1.

How do I go about converting the output to the scale of my y values (which happens to be around 15 right now, but will vary depending on the data)?

Or am I restricted to functions which vary within some kind of known range...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the tanh, and your output will be an unrestricted number. Your error function should probably be squared error.

You might have to change the gradient calculation for your back-prop, if this isn't done automatically by your framework.

Edit to add: You almost certainly want to keep the tanh (or some other non-linearity) between the recurrent connections, so remove it only for the output connection.

Comment: Ah, nice.  And if I had a LSTM net, I would need a layer on top of the LSTM, without an activation function?

Comment: didn't mean to leave this hanging so long.

Answer (score 1):

In most RNNs for classification, most people use a softmax layer on top of their LSTM or tanh layers so I think you can replace the softmax with just a linear output layer. This is what some people do for regular neural networks as well as convolutional neural networks. You will still have the nonlinearity from the hidden layers, but your outputs will not be restricted within a certain range such as -1 and 1. The cost function would probably be the squared error like larspars mentioned.